# find the lowest value using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

Here is the inputs

```
[{"Organisation unit":"Barisal Division","BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014":130.3,"BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014":112.7},
{"Organisation unit":"Chittagong Division","BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014":118.4,"BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014":122.4},
{"Organisation unit":"Dhaka Division","BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014":112.9,"BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014":123.3},
{"Organisation unit":"Khulna Division","BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014":126.9,"BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014":113.2},
{"Organisation unit":"Rajshahi Division","BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014":168.5,"BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014":175.7},
{"Organisation unit":"Rangpur Division","BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014":128.5,"BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014":129},
{"Organisation unit":"Sylhet Division","BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014":200,"BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014":104.6}]
```

Here is the code how i display the inputs into a table

```
var _table_ = document.createElement('table'),
_tr_ = document.createElement('tr'),
_th_ = document.createElement('th'),
_td_ = document.createElement('td');

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable(arr) {     
     var table = _table_.cloneNode(false),
         columns = addAllColumnHeaders(arr, table);         
     for (var i=0, maxi=arr.length; i < maxi; ++i) {
         var tr = _tr_.cloneNode(false);
        for (var j=0, maxj=columns.length; j < maxj ; ++j) {
             var td = _td_.cloneNode(false);         
             cellValue = arr[i][columns[j]];                                                    
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][columns[j]] || ''));            
             tr.appendChild(td);             
         }
         table.appendChild(tr);
     }
     return table;
 }

 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(arr, table)
 {
     var columnSet = [],
         tr = _tr_.cloneNode(false);
     for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i < l; i++) {
         for (var key in arr[i]) {
             if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && columnSet.indexOf(key)===-1) {
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 var th = _th_.cloneNode(false);
                 th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
                 tr.appendChild(th);
             }
         }
     }
     table.appendChild(tr);
     return columnSet;
 }
```

And the output is look like this

[image]

Now i how i find out the lowest value between the column 2 and column 3 for each row and make the background color as red of the lowest value

[**here is the code**](https://jsfiddle.net/munnavhai/235e5voc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by first computing the lowest value in either column 2 or 3:

```
var smallest = Infinity;
myList.forEach(function (i) {
    smallest = Math.min(
        smallest,
        i['BCG Coverage (EPI) Jan to Jun 2014'],
        i['BCG Coverage (EPI) Jul to Dec 2014']
    );
});
```

Then in the inner-most loop of your `buildHtmlTable` function check the value you are building a `<td>` for against the lowest value; if they match, add a background color of red to the `<td>`:

```
for (var j=0, maxj=columns.length; j < maxj ; ++j) {
    var td = _td_.cloneNode(false);
    cellValue = arr[i][columns[j]];

    // Add red background if cellValue is the smallest value.
    if (cellValue === smallest) td.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][columns[j]] || ''));
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

Comment: what is the mylist here

Comment: actually i think i miss place the first section of code and aslo put wrong variable as mylist

Comment: @jox thanks for putting it into the fiddle.  I missed it in the original post.

Comment: thank you @jox but did you see the result its only make red the last row but i want it for every row

Comment: @moinkhan well, I don't think you want it for every row. I suppose you want it for every column in the regarding row. The easiest would be to just change the "td" to "tr" in the line that sets the color. See https://jsfiddle.net/235e5voc/3/